How can I draw a circuit diagram from of a pyspice model?
Does anyone know how to pass a pyspice model to a function that draws a circuit diagram? It would help me to check if I designed it correctly.
I printed the model, but this is not very helpful and I cannot get it to work with schemdraw.

You can try something like my example to produce the following circuit:

The code:
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm
from PySpice.Spice.Netlist import Circuit
from PySpice.Unit import *

circuit = Circuit('Example Circuit')
circuit.R(1, '1', '2', 1@u_kΩ)
circuit.C(1, '2', '0', 1@u_uF)
circuit.V(1, '1', '0', 5@u_V)

# Function to draw the circuit
def draw_circuit(circuit):
    with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
        for element in circuit.elements:
            if element.name.startswith('R'):
                d += elm.Resistor().label(element.name)
            elif element.name.startswith('C'):
                d += elm.Capacitor().label(element.name)
            elif element.name.startswith('V'):
                d += elm.SourceV().label(element.name)
        d.draw()

draw_circuit(circuit)

About the packages:
pip install schemdraw
pip install pyspice


works great, thank you!

I just noticed that it draws everything in one line. I cannot find a function that draws complex circuits. Cannot imagine how people simulate circuits with hundreds of components without checking with a diagram.

For circuits with hundreds of components, manually drawing the schematic in schemdraw would be impractical. In that case, I think u should use specialized circuit design software like KiCad, Eagle, or Altium Designer...
